# ionic 2 and iOS10 the CSP struggle

Tags: cordova, ionic2, ios10

I am developing an app for android and iOS 10 with ionic 2/Angular 2.

My app works perfectly on android(5.0~7.0). But on iOS 10, my app wont get pass the white screen on startup.

My app uses angular2 http request to get JSON from my server, and few other cordova-plugins(Zip, File, File-Transfer) and ionic2 storage(I did not install cordova sqlite) are in use.

I did days of searching about it and I believe the solution is in setting the Content-Security-Policy meta tags correctly.

However, I have tried various meta tags but unfortunately, I'm still stuck with white screen on iOS 10.
(Android work's both with or without the CSP tag)

I have tried updating, re-installing all the components and plugins. Tried adding, removing os platforms, ionic state reset etc... but still hopeless with no solution.

Here's my current meta tag in '/src/index.html' (inside head tag and above the title tag):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src gap://ready file://* *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; img-src 'self' data: blob: *; media-src 'self' mediastream: blob:; connect-src * blob:">
```

And my iOS emulator(iPhone SE iOS10.2) console log on starting my app:

> Jan 17 19:48:24 baksagimms-Mac-Pro CoreSimulatorBridge[32274]:
>   Pasteboard change listener callback port 
>   registered Jan 17 19:48:41 baksagimms-Mac-Pro
>   CoreSimulatorBridge[32274]: Pasteboard change listener callback port
>    registered Jan 17 19:48:43
>   baksagimms-Mac-Pro CoreSimulatorBridge[32274]: Pasteboard change
>   listener callback port  registered Jan 17
>   19:48:43 baksagimms-Mac-Pro CoreSimulatorBridge[32274]: Pasteboard
>   change listener callback port  registered
>   Jan 17 19:48:43 baksagimms-Mac-Pro CoreSimulatorBridge[32274]:
>   Pasteboard change listener callback port 
>   registered Jan 17 19:48:44 baksagimms-Mac-Pro
>   CoreSimulatorBridge[32274]: Pasteboard change listener callback port
>    registered Jan 17 19:48:44
>   baksagimms-Mac-Pro DTServiceHub[32275]: Could not create service named
>   com.apple.instruments.server.services.processcontrol.posixspawn Jan 17
>   19:48:45 baksagimms-Mac-Pro CoreSimulatorBridge[32274]: Pasteboard
>   change listener callback port  registered
>   Jan 17 19:48:45 baksagimms-Mac-Pro CoreSimulatorBridge[32274]:
>   Requesting installation of
>   file:///Users/blackstone/IdeaProjects/artistapp_dia/album_app/platforms/ios/build/emulator/album_app.app/
>   with options: {
>         CFBundleIdentifier = "com.ionicframework.albumapp837617";
>         PackageType = Developer;
>         SimulatorRootPath = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk";
>         SimulatorUserPath = "/Users/blackstone/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BA74E51F-A0B7-4662-B483-EE053FA53DAB/data";
>     } Jan 17 19:48:45 baksagimms-Mac-Pro installd[32260]: 0x700001f6a000
>   -[MIClientConnection _doInstallationForURL:withOptions:completion:]: Install of
>   "/Users/blackstone/IdeaProjects/artistapp_dia/album_app/platforms/ios/build/emulator/album_app.app"
>   type Developer (LSInstallType = (null)) requested by
>   CoreSimulatorBridge (pid 32274) Jan 17 19:48:45 baksagimms-Mac-Pro
>   installd[32260]: 0x700001f6a000 MDMCreateDeltaDirectory: calling
>   MDMDirectoryDiff with:    state->old_bundle:
>   /Users/blackstone/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BA74E51F-A0B7-4662-B483-EE053FA53DAB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E8A8A135-71C8-404A-8D36-501C7ECC02AC/album_app.app
>     state->new_bundle:
>   /Users/blackstone/IdeaProjects/artistapp_dia/album_app/platforms/ios/build/emulator/album_app.app
>     state->dst_bundle:
>   /Users/blackstone/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BA74E51F-A0B7-4662-B483-EE053FA53DAB/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.rfQKOU/extracted/Payload//album_app.app,
>   binaryDiff flag: FALSE        dst_ipa:
>   /Users/blackstone/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BA74E51F-A0B7-4662-B483-EE053FA53DAB/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.rfQKOU/extracted
>   Jan 17 19:48:45 baksagimms-Mac-Pro installd[32260]: 0x700001de1000
>   __MDMDirectoryDiff_block_invoke.37: calling writeDictToFile with: /Users/blackstone/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BA74E51F-A0B7-4662-B483-EE053FA53DAB/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.rfQKOU/extracted/ManifestCache.plist
>   Jan 17 19:48:45 baksagimms-Mac-Pro installd[32260]: 0x700001de1000
>   writeDictToFile: ==== Successfully wrote Manifest cache to
>   /Users/blackstone/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BA74E51F-A0B7-4662-B483-EE053FA53DAB/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.rfQKOU/extracted/ManifestCache.plist
>   Jan 17 19:48:46 baksagimms-Mac-Pro SpringBoard[32264]:
>   [KeyboardArbiter] HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus Jan
>   17 19:48:46 baksagimms-Mac-Pro installd[32260]: 0x700001f6a000
>   -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing  Jan 17 19:48:46 baksagimms-Mac-Pro
>   installd[32260]: 0x700001f6a000 -[MIInstallableBundlePatch
>   applyPatchWithError:]: Attempting patch update of
>   com.ionicframework.albumapp837617 from 0.0.1 (0.0.1) to 0.0.1 (0.0.1)
>   Jan 17 19:48:46 baksagimms-Mac-Pro
>   com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.BA74E51F-A0B7-4662-B483-EE053FA53DAB.launchd_sim[32248]
>   (UIKitApplication:com.ionicframework.albumapp837617[0x6f91][32345]):
>   Service exited due to Killed: 9 Jan 17 19:48:46 baksagimms-Mac-Pro
>   backboardd[32266]: [Common] Unable to get short BSD proc info for
>   32345: No such file or directory Jan 17 19:48:46 baksagimms-Mac-Pro
>   backboardd[32266]: [Common] Unable to get proc info for 32345: No such
>   file or directory Jan 17 19:48:46 baksagimms-Mac-Pro
>   assertiond[32269]: notify_suspend_pid() failed with error 7 Jan 17
>   19:48:47 baksagimms-Mac-Pro syslogd[32250]: Disabling module
>   com.apple.appinstallation writes to
>   /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/AppInstallation/AppInstallation.log
>   following 6 failures (Operation Failed) Jan 17 19:48:47
>   baksagimms-Mac-Pro installd[32260]: 0x700001f6a000
>   -[MIInstallableBundle _refreshUUIDForContainer:withError:]: Data container for com.ionicframework.albumapp837617 is now at
>   /Users/blackstone/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BA74E51F-A0B7-4662-B483-EE053FA53DAB/data/Containers/Data/Application/1EE6DD04-3B43-4E5B-9A00-01841C9DD3A1
>   Jan 17 19:48:47 baksagimms-Mac-Pro installd[32260]: 0x700001f6a000
>   -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for com.ionicframework.albumapp837617 at
>   /Users/blackstone/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BA74E51F-A0B7-4662-B483-EE053FA53DAB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6D2D037E-10B7-43E0-B95B-709FCB9493F3
>   Jan 17 19:48:47 baksagimms-Mac-Pro installd[32260]: 0x700001f6a000
>   -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Install Successful; Staging: 1.50s; Waiting: 0.00s; Preflight/Patch: 0.44s, Verifying:
>   0.01s; Overall: 2.05s Jan 17 19:48:47 baksagimms-Mac-Pro appstored[32330]: [default] LaunchServices observer: Installed (
>         " com.ionicframework.albumapp837617
>   file:///Users/blackstone/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BA74E51F-A0B7-4662-B483-EE053FA53DAB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6D2D037E-10B7-43E0-B95B-709FCB9493F3/album_app.app
>   >"     )
>   {A703FE87-2740-4C0B-8AA7-9125511A3381 256} Jan 17 19:48:47
>   baksagimms-Mac-Pro SpringBoard[32264]: [default] LaunchServices
>   observer: Installed (
>         " com.ionicframework.albumapp837617
>   file:///Users/blackstone/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BA74E51F-A0B7-4662-B483-EE053FA53DAB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6D2D037E-10B7-43E0-B95B-709FCB9493F3/album_app.app
>   >"     )
>   {A703FE87-2740-4C0B-8AA7-9125511A3381 256} Jan 17 19:48:47
>   baksagimms-Mac-Pro routined[32254]: [default] LaunchServices observer:
>   Installed (
>         " com.ionicframework.albumapp837617
>   file:///Users/blackstone/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BA74E51F-A0B7-4662-B483-EE053FA53DAB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6D2D037E-10B7-43E0-B95B-709FCB9493F3/album_app.app
>   >"     )
>   {A703FE87-2740-4C0B-8AA7-9125511A3381 256} Jan 17 19:48:47
>   baksagimms-Mac-Pro nsurlsessiond[32302]: [default] LaunchServices
>   observer: Installed (
>         " com.ionicframework.albumapp837617
>   file:///Users/blackstone/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BA74E51F-A0B7-4662-B483-EE053FA53DAB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6D2D037E-10B7-43E0-B95B-709FCB9493F3/album_app.app
>   >"     )
>   {A703FE87-2740-4C0B-8AA7-9125511A3381 256} Jan 17 19:48:47
>   baksagimms-Mac-Pro UserEventAgent[32251]: [default] LaunchServices
>   observer: Installed (
>         " com.ionicframework.albumapp837617
>   file:///Users/blackstone/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BA74E51F-A0B7-4662-B483-EE053FA53DAB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6D2D037E-10B7-43E0-B95B-709FCB9493F3/album_app.app
>   >"     )
>   {A703FE87-2740-4C0B-8AA7-9125511A3381 256} Jan 17 19:48:47
>   baksagimms-Mac-Pro passd[32319]: [default] LaunchServices observer:
>   Installed (
>         " com.ionicframework.albumapp837617
>   file:///Users/blackstone/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BA74E51F-A0B7-4662-B483-EE053FA53DAB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6D2D037E-10B7-43E0-B95B-709FCB9493F3/album_app.app
>   >"     )
>   {A703FE87-2740-4C0B-8AA7-9125511A3381 256} Jan 17 19:48:47
>   baksagimms-Mac-Pro SpringBoard[32264]: [default] LaunchServices
>   observer: Installed (
>         " com.ionicframework.albumapp837617
>   file:///Users/blackstone/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BA74E51F-A0B7-4662-B483-EE053FA53DAB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6D2D037E-10B7-43E0-B95B-709FCB9493F3/album_app.app
>   >"     )
>   {A703FE87-2740-4C0B-8AA7-9125511A3381 256} Jan 17 19:48:47
>   baksagimms-Mac-Pro profiled[32321]: [default] LaunchServices observer:
>   Installed (
>         " com.ionicframework.albumapp837617
>   file:///Users/blackstone/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BA74E51F-A0B7-4662-B483-EE053FA53DAB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6D2D037E-10B7-43E0-B95B-709FCB9493F3/album_app.app
>   >"     )
>   {A703FE87-2740-4C0B-8AA7-9125511A3381 256} Jan 17 19:48:51
>   baksagimms-Mac-Pro CoreSimulatorBridge[32274]: Pasteboard change
>   listener callback port  registered Jan 17
>   19:48:51 baksagimms-Mac-Pro CoreSimulatorBridge[32274]: Requesting
>   launch of com.ionicframework.albumapp837617 with options: {
>         environment =     {
>         };  } Jan 17 19:48:51 baksagimms-Mac-Pro CoreSimulatorBridge[32274]: Beginning launch sequence for bundle
>   'com.ionicframework.albumapp837617'       retryTimeout: 120.000000
>   (default write com.apple.CoreSimulatorBridge LaunchRetryTimeout
>   )      bootTimeout: 300.000000 (default write
>   com.apple.CoreSimulatorBridge BootRetryTimeout )       bootLeeway:
>   120.000000 (default write com.apple.CoreSimulatorBridge BootLeeway )       Note: Use 'xcrun simctl spawn booted defaults write
>     ' to modify defaults in the booted Simulator
>   device.   Simulator booted at: 2017-01-17 10:27:11 +0000  Current time:
>   2017-01-17 10:48:51 +0000     Within boot leeway: NO Jan 17 19:48:51
>   baksagimms-Mac-Pro CoreSimulatorBridge[32274]: Launch attempt #0 for
>   bundle 'com.ionicframework.albumapp837617', have been trying to launch
>   for 0 seconds. Modern launch services = YES Jan 17 19:48:51
>   baksagimms-Mac-Pro CoreSimulatorBridge[32274]: Got LSBundleProxy for
>   'com.ionicframework.albumapp837617', sequenceNumber 256, cacheGUID
>   A703FE87-2740-4C0B-8AA7-9125511A3381 Jan 17 19:48:51
>   baksagimms-Mac-Pro CoreSimulatorBridge[32274]: [Common]
>   [FBSSystemService][0xed8e] Sending request to open
>   "com.ionicframework.albumapp837617" Jan 17 19:48:51 baksagimms-Mac-Pro
>   CoreSimulatorBridge[32274]: [Common] [FBSSystemService][0xed8e]
>   Request successful:  Jan 17 19:48:51 baksagimms-Mac-Pro
>   CoreSimulatorBridge[32274]: Launch successful for
>   'com.ionicframework.albumapp837617' Jan 17 19:48:52 baksagimms-Mac-Pro
>   album_app[32697]: objc[32697]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in
>   both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   (0x1061fe998) and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
>   (0x105f7d880). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>   Jan 17 19:48:52 baksagimms-Mac-Pro logd[32259]: metadata shared cached
>   uuid is null (using logd's shared cache info) album_app (32697) Jan 17
>   19:48:52 baksagimms-Mac-Pro logd[32259]: Failed to harvest strings for
>   pathless uuid '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' Jan 17 19:48:52
>   baksagimms-Mac-Pro album_app[32697]: assertion failed: 16C67 14C89:
>   libxpc.dylib + 62677 [0339A402-6531-30E9-8BC2-589C463CD6D6]: 0x7d Jan
>   17 19:48:52 baksagimms-Mac-Pro album_app[32697]: Apache Cordova native
>   platform version 4.3.1 is starting. Jan 17 19:48:52 baksagimms-Mac-Pro
>   album_app[32697]: Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES Jan 17
>   19:48:52 baksagimms-Mac-Pro album_app[32697]: Using UIWebView Jan 17
>   19:48:52 baksagimms-Mac-Pro album_app[32697]:
>   [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.047028ms Jan 17 19:48:52
>   baksagimms-Mac-Pro album_app[32697]: Unlimited access to network
>   resources Jan 17 19:48:52 baksagimms-Mac-Pro album_app[32697]:
>   [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 1.711011ms Jan 17 19:48:52
>   baksagimms-Mac-Pro album_app[32697]: [CDVTimer][gesturehandler]
>   0.056982ms Jan 17 19:48:52 baksagimms-Mac-Pro album_app[32697]: [CDVTimer][file] 2.811015ms Jan 17 19:48:52 baksagimms-Mac-Pro
>   album_app[32697]: [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 16.559005ms Jan 17 19:48:52
>   baksagimms-Mac-Pro album_app[32697]: [CDVTimer][statusbar] 4.653037ms
>   Jan 17 19:48:52 baksagimms-Mac-Pro album_app[32697]:
>   [CDVTimer][keyboard] 0.611007ms Jan 17 19:48:52 baksagimms-Mac-Pro
>   album_app[32697]: [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 28.108001ms Jan 17
>   19:48:52 baksagimms-Mac-Pro album_app[32697]: Resetting plugins due to
>   page load. Jan 17 19:48:52 baksagimms-Mac-Pro album_app[32697]:
>   Finished load of:
>   file:///Users/blackstone/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BA74E51F-A0B7-4662-B483-EE053FA53DAB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6D2D037E-10B7-43E0-B95B-709FCB9493F3/album_app.app/www/index.html
>   Jan 17 19:48:52 baksagimms-Mac-Pro album_app[32697]: DEVICE READY
>   FIRED AFTER 55 ms

App will work just fine on iOS10 if no additional cordova plugins are installed.
Anyone who has any info or solution about this please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> App will work just fine on iOS10 if no additional cordova plugins are installed

This would suggest to me that the plugins are the cause of the problem, not the CSP. You can check this by running the app in iOS 9 Simulator/Device because iOS 9 doesn't care about the CSP.

From your log output, the `deviceready` event is firing so the Cordova environment is starting up. I would connect the Safari remote debugger to the Webview. There may be a console error message if you reload the Webview using the remote debugger's "Refresh button". If not, I'd add some breakpoints, starting out from the first actions once `deviceready` has fired to see where it's failing.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. heres what i found out so far: cordova.file returns undefined in my app. while it returns full system file directory objects in android. and when using cordova.file.dataDirectory, it makes my app stuck on white screen. but strangely it returns proper data when console.log(cordova.file) in xcode console. any idea why this is happening?

Comment: oh... they just added cordova-file iOS10 build is failing. just yesterday.